# How can I add a background to my png image?

Tags: php

I have a default image that I want my users when they first create their profile to have, and I need to each one of them have a different background color but with the same base shape that will be in a png file, I can do this by creating for each background color create a png but I dont think it might be the best choice. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Imagick](https://www.php.net/imagick) extension to work on your image. You can set a background color for your transparent png image by simply doing this

```
shell_exec("convert testimage.png -fill '#CCCCCC00' -opaque none image_wth_bgcolor.png");
```

This will give a slight gray(#CCCCCC) background to the the image.
See this [link](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=11398).

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to create a png file for each colour (which seems to be the only way)
and use PHP to randomly pick one of the images.